# java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: spring, solr, spring-batch

I have a spring batch job which is reading data from DB and indexing into solr.After deploying war for the first time i run it runs fine. But if i run it second time its showing exception as below

```
java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor$$Lambda$5793/1735313067@63e1224 rejected from org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor@3411eba2[Terminated, pool size = 0, active threads = 0, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 157]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at org.apache.solr.common.util.ExecutorUtil$MDCAwareThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ExecutorUtil.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.addRunner(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:429)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.request(ConcurrentUpdateSolrClient.java:527)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrRequest.process(SolrRequest.java:194)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.add(SolrClient.java:106)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.addBeans(SolrClient.java:357)
    at org.apache.solr.client.solrj.SolrClient.addBeans(SolrClient.java:329)

    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1557.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.doProceed(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:136)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.invoke(DelegatingIntroductionInterceptor.java:124)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy1112.write(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:188)
```

I think connection to solr is refused second time due to some issues.Pls help

Comment: This error means thread pool size is zero, you need to increase this to some number.

Comment: Please post the full stack trace, the root cause is not shown.

Answer (score 0):

This means you closed the `CloudSolrClient` and then tried to add more work with it after it was closed.

So you probably have some code like this:

```
try (CloudSolrClient solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder()
        .withZkHost(SOLR_ZK_HOSTS)
        .withZkChroot(SOLR_ZK_CHROOT)
        .withConnectionTimeout(10000)
        .withSocketTimeout(60000)
        .build()) {
  ... start all threads that do the work here ...
}

wait for threads to complete
```

You should have instead did this:

```
try (CloudSolrClient solrClient = new CloudSolrClient.Builder()
        .withZkHost(SOLR_ZK_HOSTS)
        .withZkChroot(SOLR_ZK_CHROOT)
        .withConnectionTimeout(10000)
        .withSocketTimeout(60000)
        .build()) {
  ... start all threads that do the work here ...
  wait for threads to complete
}
```

Notice how the `wait for threads to complete` is *inside* the try with resources loop. The result of not waiting for the threads to complete is that you ended up closing the solrClient before the files were all added.